# Issues with Fraction on Axes Label in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, mathjax, axis-labels

Trying to put a fraction on my y axis label: `plt.ylabel("$\frac{d}{dt}[C]$")`

but I am getting a weird error:

```
rac{d}{dt}[C]$
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

I know that there is nothing wrong with my mathjax syntax. Does Matplotlib not do complete mathjax?

Comment: try adding a "r" before the first quote >> plt.ylabel(r"$\frac{d}{dt}[C]$")

Comment: The "r" indicates that the string must be interpreted as a "raw" string and the that \f is not a special character

Comment: That works. Great, thanks.

Comment: A way to do this in a more programatic way is instead of the `raw`-formatting is to replace characters using  a dictionary `trans_dict = dict( '\': '\\' , '{': '{{{', '}': '}}}' } )`  so that `"$\frac{d}{dt}[C]$"` is replaced by `"$\\frac{{{d}}}{{{dt}}}[C]$"`.                                                                                                                                          

Here I should mention that the reason to use triple curly braces is that both LaTeX and python use them in `f`-strings, and  for LaTeX  `{{{{{{}}}}}}` is equivalent to `{}`.